# Get products in stock with qty > 0 of configurable products

Tags: magento-1.7, stock, product-collection, collection-filtering

Whats the best way to get a collection with products which are in stock and have a positive qty.

I already use the following to filter `in stock`, but this give me also products with qty=0, because I allow backorders

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about his - you check that the quantity is greater than 0:

```
$in_stock_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->joinField('qty',
                                     'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                                     'qty',
                                     'product_id=entity_id',
                                     '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                                     'left')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0));
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I suppose you need to grab the configurable products, and then for each item check if they are in stock? Unfortunately I do not have any stores with configurable items to test this on.

```
// get your configurable products collection
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable'); 


// then loop through and check each product if in stock
foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {

    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();

    echo $product->getName() . ' has a stock of value of ' . $stock;
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Looks like, this works..

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work for configurable products.. since the stock of the configurable is zero

Comment: I've edited my first answer, hopefully this will get you closer to what you want. I guess you'll still have to edit it a little

Comment: Of course this would work, but this seems not very fast on big stores - I hoped that there's a better solution only in sql

Answer (score 2):

Late arriving answer, had a need to do some work on this code though, so here you go. It only takes a few joins, works for configurable and simple products, haven't tested against bundles.

```
$entity_type_id = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_product')->getEntityTypeId();
$attribute_id = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'status');


$product_collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array(
            'css1' => $products->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')
        ),
        'e.entity_id = css1.product_id and css1.stock_id =1 AND css1.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
        ''
    )->joinLeft(
        array(
            'cpsl' => $products->getTable('catalog/product_super_link')
        ),
        'cpsl.parent_id = e.entity_id',
        ''
    )->joinLeft(
        array(
            'css2' => $products->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')
        ),
        'css2.product_id = cpsl.product_id and css1.stock_id =1 AND css1.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
        ''
    )->joinLeft(
        array(
            'cpei' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'
        ),
        "cpei.entity_id = cpsl.product_id AND cpei.entity_type_id = $entity_type_id and cpei.attribute_id = $attribute_id AND (cpei.value IS NULL OR cpei.value = " . Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED . ")",
        ''
    )->group(
        'e.entity_id'
    )->columns(
        array(
            'qty' => new Zend_Db_Expr ("IF(`e`.`type_id` = 'simple', `css1`.qty, sum(css2.qty))")
        )
    )->having(
        'qty > 0'
);
```

Comment: yeah, so did I, was surprised to find I'd written it!

Comment: what was $entity_type_id and $attribute_id referring to?

Comment: I edited it in, but basically entity_type_id for product (usually 4) and the attribute_id for `status`

Comment: Ah thanks, I've replaced these in my code with `Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'status')` and `Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId()`.  I think I'm having issues with the 'column' section though as magento throws `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'qty' in 'having clause'`, and running the assembled SQL query manually without adding the qty condition produces an SQL syntax error, any advice?

Comment: check the generated SQL then, `echo (string) $product_collection->getSelect();` before you try loading it

Comment: I checked the string with `$collection->getSelect()->assemble()` which produced the query which was causing the mentioned errors

Comment: so you need to work out why/how the query is wrong, is it generated wrong, is it invalid with your version of mysql for some reason?

Comment: Weirdly enough the raw query has started working while running through PHPStorm, but still doesn't work through magento, I'll look into mysql versions, thanks

Comment: It looks like the issue might be coming from somewhere else in magento, although the query works when running through phpstorm but not raw in the console

Comment: Hi Richard, Looks like the issue was stemming from me applying this in an observer - when the collection was then paginated, the generated qty column was stripped out, meaning the `having` clause was invalid!  Decided to approach a different way and use a cron job to generate a product attribute based on simple qty values instead, which I'll use to filter the collection by